# Replace superscript and italic with HTML tags in Excel sheet

Tags: html, excel, vba, superscript, italic

I need to get rid of the superscript and the italic, adding an HTML tag to surround the word/letter.

For example:

My phrase has a superscript<sup>1</sup> and also has an *italic* word.

Should be converted to:

```
My phrase has a superscript<sup>1</sup> and also has an <i>italic</i> word.
```

I have found a "solution" for that (it locates where the superscript and italic are and store its position), but it had lots of problems. I got to make that work for a while:

```
Sub TagSubstitution()
    Dim lngStart_i As Long
    Dim lngFinish_i As Long
    Dim lngStart_sup As Long
    Dim lngFinish_sup As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim k_i As Long
    Dim k_sup As Long
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim rngConstants As Range
    Dim cellAddress As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngConstants = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rngConstants Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each rngCell In rngConstants.Cells
            Dim listStart_i() As Long, X_i As Long
            Dim listFinish_i() As Long, Y_i As Long
            Dim listStart_sup() As Long, X_sup As Long
            Dim listFinish_sup() As Long, Y_sup As Long
            X_i = 0
            Y_i = 0
            X_sup = 0
            Y_sup = 0
            ReDim Preserve listStart_i(X)
            ReDim Preserve listFinish_i(Y)
            ReDim Preserve listStart_sup(X)
            ReDim Preserve listFinish_sup(Y)
            lngStart_i = 0
            lngStart_sup = 0
            For n = 1 To Len(rngCell.Value) + 1
                If rngCell.Characters(n, 1).Font.Italic Then
                    If lngStart_i = 0 Then
                        lngStart_i = n
                        ReDim Preserve listStart_i(0 To X_i)
                        listStart_i(X_i) = lngStart_i
                        X_i = X_i + 1
                    End If
                ElseIf lngStart_i <> 0 Then
                    If Not rngCell.Characters(n, 1).Font.Italic Then
                        lngFinish_i = n
                        ReDim Preserve listFinish_i(0 To Y_i)
                        listFinish_i(Y_i) = lngFinish_i
                        Y_i = Y_i + 1
                        lngStart_i = 0
                    End If
                End If
                If rngCell.Characters(n, 1).Font.Superscript Then
                    If lngStart_sup = 0 Then
                        lngStart_sup = n
                        ReDim Preserve listStart_sup(0 To X_sup)
                        listStart_sup(X_sup) = lngStart_sup
                        X_sup = X_sup + 1
                    End If
                ElseIf lngStart_sup <> 0 Then
                    If Not rngCell.Characters(n, 1).Font.Superscript Then
                        lngFinish_sup = n
                        ReDim Preserve listFinish_sup(0 To Y_sup)
                        listFinish_sup(Y_sup) = lngFinish_sup
                        Y_sup = Y_sup + 1
                        lngStart_sup = 0
                    End If
                End If
            Next n
            If listStart_i(0) <> 0 Then
                Dim sup_addition_i As Integer
                sup_addition_i = 0
                For k_i = LBound(listStart_i) To UBound(listStart_i)
                    start_value = listStart_i(k_i) + sup_addition_i
                    finish_value = listFinish_i(k_i) + sup_addition_i
                    If Len(rngCell.Value) > 255 Then
                        content_len = finish_value + 1 - start_value
                        before_content = Left(rngCell, start_value - 1)
                        after_content = Right(rngCell, Len(rngCell.Value) + content_len - finish_value)
                        after_content = Left(after_content, content_len - 1)
                        end_content = Right(rngCell, Len(rngCell.Value) + 1 - finish_value)
                        rngCell = before_content & "<i>" & after_content & "</i>" & end_content
                    Else
                        rngCell.Characters(start_value, 0).Insert "<i>"
                        rngCell.Characters(finish_value + 3, 0).Insert "</i>"
                    End If
                    sup_addition_i = 7 * (k_i + 1)
                Next k_i
                rngCell.Font.Italic = False
            If listStart_sup(0) <> 0 Then
                Dim sup_addition_sup As Integer
                sup_addition_p = 0 - sup_addition_i
                For k_sup = LBound(listStart_sup) To UBound(listStart_sup)
                    start_value = listStart_sup(k_sup) + sup_addition_sup
                    finish_value = listFinish_sup(k_sup) + sup_addition_sup
                    If Len(rngCell.Value) > 255 Then
                        content_len = finish_value + 1 - start_value
                        before_content = Left(rngCell, start_value - 1)
                        after_content = Right(rngCell, Len(rngCell.Value) + content_len - finish_value)
                        after_content = Left(after_content, content_len - 1)
                        end_content = Right(rngCell, Len(rngCell.Value) + 1 - finish_value)
                        rngCell = before_content & "<sup>" & after_content & "</sup>" & end_content
                    Else
                        rngCell.Characters(start_value, 0).Insert "<sup>"
                        rngCell.Characters(finish_value + 5, 0).Insert "</sup>"
                    End If
                    sup_addition_sup = 11 * (k_sup + 1) - sup_addition_i
                Next k_sup
                rngCell.Font.Superscript = False
            End If
            End If
        Next rngCell
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem with this code is that when I have both superscript and italic on the same cell I get the problem that, after inserting italic, the position of the superscript is not the same as before. So I misplace every `<sup>` tag after that...

I am a newbie in VBA and I don't know the proper way that I could accomplish this solution.

**Edit**

Another approach that I've tried:

```
Sub AdicionarTags()
    Dim xSh As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xSh In Worksheets
        xSh.Select
        Call TagItalic
        Call TagSuperscript
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub TagItalic()
    Dim lngStart As Long
    Dim lngFinish As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim rngConstants As Range
    Dim cellAddress As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngConstants = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rngConstants Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each rngCell In rngConstants.Cells
            Dim listStart() As Long, X As Long
            Dim listFinish() As Long, Y As Long
            X = 0
            Y = 0
            ReDim Preserve listStart(X)
            ReDim Preserve listFinish(Y)
            lngStart = 0
            For n = 1 To Len(rngCell.Value) + 1
                If rngCell.Characters(n, 1).Font.Italic Then
                    If lngStart = 0 Then
                        lngStart = n
                        ReDim Preserve listStart(0 To X)
                        listStart(X) = lngStart
                        X = X + 1
                    End If
                ElseIf lngStart <> 0 Then
                    If Not rngCell.Characters(n, 1).Font.Italic Then
                        lngFinish = n
                        ReDim Preserve listFinish(0 To Y)
                        listFinish(Y) = lngFinish
                        Y = Y + 1
                        lngStart = 0
                    End If
                End If
            Next n
            If listStart(0) <> 0 Then
                Dim sup_addition As Integer
                sup_addition = 0
                For k = LBound(listStart) To UBound(listStart)
                    start_value = listStart(k) + sup_addition
                    finish_value = listFinish(k) + sup_addition
                    content_len = finish_value + 1 - start_value
                    before_content = Left(rngCell, start_value - 1)
                    after_content = Right(rngCell, Len(rngCell.Value) + content_len - finish_value)
                    after_content = Left(after_content, content_len - 1)
                    end_content = Right(rngCell, Len(rngCell.Value) + 1 - finish_value)
                    rngCell = before_content & "<i>" & after_content & "</i>" & end_content
                    sup_addition = 7 * (k + 1)
                Next k
                rngCell.Font.Italic = False
            End If
        Next rngCell
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
Sub TagSuperscript()
    Dim lngStart As Long
    Dim lngFinish As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim rngConstants As Range
    Dim cellAddress As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngConstants = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rngConstants Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each rngCell In rngConstants.Cells
            Dim listStart() As Long, X As Long
            Dim listFinish() As Long, Y As Long
            X = 0
            Y = 0
            ReDim Preserve listStart(X)
            ReDim Preserve listFinish(Y)
            lngStart = 0
            For n = 1 To Len(rngCell.Value) + 1
                If rngCell.Characters(n, 1).Font.Superscript Then
                    If lngStart = 0 Then
                        lngStart = n
                        ReDim Preserve listStart(0 To X)
                        listStart(X) = lngStart
                        X = X + 1
                    End If
                ElseIf lngStart <> 0 Then
                    If Not rngCell.Characters(n, 1).Font.Superscript Then
                        lngFinish = n
                        ReDim Preserve listFinish(0 To Y)
                        listFinish(Y) = lngFinish
                        Y = Y + 1
                        lngStart = 0
                    End If
                End If
            Next n
            If listStart(0) <> 0 Then
                Dim sup_addition As Integer
                sup_addition = 0
                For k = LBound(listStart) To UBound(listStart)
                    start_value = listStart(k) + sup_addition
                    finish_value = listFinish(k) + sup_addition
                    content_len = finish_value + 1 - start_value
                    before_content = Left(rngCell, start_value - 1)
                    after_content = Right(rngCell, Len(rngCell.Value) + content_len - finish_value)
                    after_content = Left(after_content, content_len - 1)
                    end_content = Right(rngCell, Len(rngCell.Value) + 1 - finish_value)
                    rngCell = before_content & "<sup>" & after_content & "</sup>" & end_content
                    sup_addition = 11 * (k + 1)
                Next k
                rngCell.Font.Superscript = False
            End If
        Next rngCell
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

But this time the problem is that after running the first `Sub`, when I replace the cell, the style is lost and when the second function runs it has none of the previous formatting.

Comment: The `For n = 1 To Len(rngCell.Value) + 1` loop expression is also invalid after the first insert: `Len(rngCell.Value)` can change at every iteration - you need something other than a `For` loop here, since you *don't* know how many iterations you'll need to complete the logic.

Comment: `Do While n <= Len(rngCell.Value) ... Loop` should re-evaluate the exit condition at each iteration; the upper bound of a `For` loop is only evaluated once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than inserting into your string, you should start building an appropriate string (`z`), similar to:

```
Option Explicit

Sub remove_italics_and_superscripts()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, rng As Range, z As String
    For Each rng In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        For i = 1 To Len(rng)
            If rng.Characters(i, 1).Font.Superscript = True Then
                For j = 0 To Len(rng) - i
                    If rng.Characters(j + i, 1).Font.Superscript = False Then Exit For
                Next j
                z = z & "<sup>" & Mid(rng.Value, i, j) & "</sup>"
            ElseIf rng.Characters(i, 1).Font.Italic = True Then
                For j = 0 To Len(rng) - i
                    If rng.Characters(j + i, 1).Font.Italic = False Then Exit For
                Next j
                z = z & "<i>" & Mid(rng.Value, i, j) & "</i>"
            Else
                z = z & Mid(rng.Value, i, 1)
                j = 1
            End If
            i = i + j - 1
        Next i
        rng.Offset(, 1).Value = z 'didn't immediately see where you output, so just out to the next column to the right
        z = ""
    Next rng
End Sub
```

I cleaned up a little of the looping/conditions that you were using.  Additionally, this removes the need for an array (note your `redim preserve`).

Comment: Nice, much better idea than trying to fix the loop condition :)

Comment: Dude... I can't thank you enough!! It worked perfectly. I just need to place the output in the same cell as before now and it was done.

Comment: I accomplished that by setting the rng.Offset(, 1).Value to rng.Offset(, 0).Value

Comment: @MatheusSant'ana you could just say `rng.value = z` and that is fine, since there isn't an offset

Comment: Even better! Thank you again.